# Pyinstaller error running script with pyzmq dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, zeromq, pyzmq

I am running into issues creating a pyinstaller(v4.2) executable with a pyzmq (v22.0.2) dependency. I created an executable by running "pyinstaller main.py". The dist folder was created without errors but when I run the executable in the terminal, I see the error in quotes below.

I did a search for this kind of issue on StackOverflow and pyinstaller's documentation with no match to my exact problem. I saw mention of a .spec file for what seemed like similar issues, though I am not sure if this is the way to go since I am unclear what pyzmq.libs\.load_order is.

Does anyone know how to overcome this error or have good leads on what I may try?

```
"C:\Users\[redacted path]\dist\main>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "zmq\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "zmq\__init__.py", line 13, in _delvewheel_init_patch_0_0_9
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\[redacted path]\\dist\\main\\pyzmq.libs\\.load_order'
[4408] Failed to execute script main

C:\Users\[redacted path]\dist\main>"
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found this solution
Downgrade to 21.0.0 using `pip install pyzmq==21.0.0`
then you can run pyinstaller again and it will run perfectly fine.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you. To anyone else following this path, you will be prompted to update some visual studio C++ code when you try to downgrade pyzmq. If you just follow the error message instructions, you will be good to go.

Comment: That do the trick for me too. I installed the version 21.0.0 and I don't have this error anymore. thks

Answer (score 1):

Find a folder called 'pyzmq.libs' in your `<local-python-path>\Lib\site-packages`.

For example, I'm using Miniconda3 here, so I got this at `C:\\Users\MyPC\Miniconda3\envs\my_env\Lib\site-packages`

Then, copy this folder to your `C:\\Users\\[redacted path]\\dist\\main` folder, and re-try the executable.

Comment: I was unable to get this pathway to work. Did you get this to work?

Comment: Yes I got this to work when trying to pack my GUI application with fman-build-system. Were you able to find where your 'zmq' package located?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably not the same as 2yr old post, but incase people are having issues like me here is some fixes I did to get pyzmq working with pyinstaller's one folder option by copying the following folders to subfolders in the subfolder "_internal". I'm using pyinstaller 6.2.0, python 3.11 , and pyzmq 25.1.1:

Copy C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyzmq.libs to a subfolder ._internal\pyzmq.libs

Copy C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zmq to a subfolder ._internal\zmq

These were the runtime errors I was getting:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '..._internal\pyzmq.libs'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq.backend.cython'