# not able to run jupyter-lab/ jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab, python-3.9

**After going through several iterations of reinstalling anaconda and jupyter-notebook, I am getting the same error**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 78, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    _delvewheel_init_patch_0_0_12()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 10, in _delvewheel_init_patch_0_0_12
    os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
    cookie = nt._add_dll_directory(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\pyzmq.libs'
```

Reinstalled pyzmq -

```
pip install pyzmq
```

Also, tried to install pyzmq using the wheel file, didn't work either.
What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your problem was similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054625/pyinstaller-error-running-script-with-pyzmq-dependency).

The solution is either to downgrade to `pyzmq` version 21:

```
pip install pyzmq==21.0.0
```

Or install [VS C++ Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) libraries (this is a [change in v. 22](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html) when compared to v. 21).